# Command for calling swi-prolog from php

Tags: php, prolog, command, swi-prolog

I am working with prolog and php. I am using php, to call prolog.
I am using swi-prolog  Version 7.1.17 and  XAMPP 1.7.7 [PHP: 5.3.8].
My command :
`$cmd ='swipl -q -f C:\Users\MyComp\Desktop\test.pl -g test,halt';`
Here `C:\Users\MyComp\Desktop\test.pl` is prolog file directory. It is worked properly. but Now I update the XAMPP version(above 1.7.7) then it is not work. but the command it is work properly in cmd in windows.How can i solve this kind of problem? Any command will using All XAMPP version for call prolog from php.

Answer (score 0):

You Try with 
`nice -n15 /software/bin/pl -f /home/popx/cgi-bin/test.pl -g test,halt`
This may be work with your specification.
See the [reference](http://www.j-paine.org/dobbs/prolog_from_php.html)

Comment: I already used this but it not work to my XAMPP, It is possible to work with that.

Comment: refer this [link](http://swi-prolog.996271.n3.nabble.com/Php-with-Prolog-td6594.html)